# Check for existence of sessions

Tags: php, session

In my code I have a lot of sessions and I'm afraid that I could forget unset() some sessions. Any solution how I can check for existence sessions with ANY name? Ofc I can do that from server-side.

Comment: by that do you mean you want to check `$_SESSION['variable']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, "how can see all the sessions", that would depend on the session storage mechanism used. You might typically find file-based session data stored as individual files in /tmp (or more accurately, if [session.save_handler](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) is 'files', the path is set by [session.save_path](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path))

If you mean "how can I see all the variables in a session", you could use [foreach](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach($_SESSION as $name=>$value)
{
     echo "$name = $value<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All sessions are stored as keys in $_SESSION so loop through that
 is that what you mean ?
or session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session.